# How to populate a popup in Spring?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, spring-mvc, popup

I do have a table. After clicking a row, I would like a popup to appear showing product details. I've tried a controller method with Bootstrap modal window, but that just does not work. Here's the method:

```
@RequestMapping("/{id}")
public String getNetworkInfo(Model model, @PathVariable String id){

    model.addAttribute("poolHashrate", netService.getPoolHashrate(new Long(id)));

    return "networkDetails";
}
```

And a view body:

```
<body>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>

</body>
```

It returns a view that was supposed to be a popup, but I feel like I don't get the idea. No data there. Just a sample popup.

Comment: do you want to the return result of `networkDetails` to be the content of the pop up window?

Comment: Well, I just want to display the result of `netService.getPoolHashrate(new Long(id))` function.

Comment: I have added an answer,you can check it

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ajax` to achieve it

> First make the controller return to a jsp page,then use the content of
>   the jsp page to form a dialog and open it.

Suppose the jsp page for `networkDetails` is as below,it only include the detail info, if not you can create a jsp page for it:

```
<div id="networkDetail">
  ${poolHashrate}
<div>
```

Then we can put the content of it to the pop up window:

```
$.ajax({
    url:url,
    type:"get",
    success:function(data){
       $("#dialog").html(data);//data is the return page of "networkDetails"
       $("#dialog").dialog({//open the dialog
       //... other code to init a dialog
       });
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm new to Js. What is $("#dialog").html? Is it a newly created .html file?

Comment: it is jquery,use it to set the content of the element

Answer (score 0):

I used Jquery to open the modal popup and populate the values in modal popup as well.

Below is modal code:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
                        aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">EDIT</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>
                        <input type="text" class="input-sm" id="txtfname" />
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <input type="text" class="input-sm" id="txtlname" />
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.modal-content -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div>
```

Jquery code: It populates and open the modal - myModal as defined above

```
<script>
$(document)
.ready(
    function () {

    $('table tbody tr  td')
    .on(
        'click',
        function () {
        $("#myModal").modal("show");
        $("#txtfname")
        .val(
            $(this).closest(
                'tr')
            .children()[0].textContent);
        $("#txtlname")
        .val(
            $(this).closest(
                'tr')
            .children()[1].textContent);
    });

});
</script>
```

Table code:

```
<table id="example" class="table table-condensed table-hover table-bordered"
                        width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>$3,120</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Nixon Tiger</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>$3,120</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```